# How to restore the data after search react native cloud firestore

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

So i have a problem that after done searching once name, when start type to search again.

the data won't show again but after goBack() and go to the screen again data show, but only can search once more

Can anyone help

Thank You

```
const nameList = () => {
  const [daftar, setDaftar] = useState<any>([]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState<any>('');

  const searchName = (input) => {
    let data = daftar;
    let searchData = data.filter((item) => {
      return (
        item?.name.toLowerCase().includes(input.toLowerCase()) ||
        item?.address?.toLowerCase().includes(input?.toLowerCase())
      );
    });
    setDaftar(searchData);
  };
     

  return (
    <Div flex={1} bg="#fff">
      <Div py={heightPercentageToDP(1)} px={heightPercentageToDP(2)}>
        <Input
          focusBorderColor={PRIMARY_COLOR}
          placeholder="Search..."
          onChangeText={(val) => searchName(val)}
          // value={search}
        />
      </Div>
    </Div>
  );
};
```

Comment: How do you initially set `daftar` state?

Comment: I think you need to update the state for that pls use React.useEffect and in dependency add daftar

Answer (score 2):

You should keep the filtered data in a different state.

Set the same data to both the `deftar` and the `filteredList` when the page is first opened. when you search you use the `deftar` datas and the result is set to `filteredList`

In the page use `filteredList`

```
const nameList = () => {
  const [daftar, setDaftar] = useState<any>([]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState<any>('');
  const [filteredList, setFilterList] = useState<any>([]);

  const searchName = (input) => {
    let data = daftar;
    let searchData = data.filter((item) => {
      return (
        item?.name.toLowerCase().includes(input.toLowerCase()) ||
        item?.address?.toLowerCase().includes(input?.toLowerCase())
      );
    });
    setFilterList(searchData);
  };
     

  return (
    <Div flex={1} bg="#fff">
      <Div py={heightPercentageToDP(1)} px={heightPercentageToDP(2)}>
        <Input
          focusBorderColor={PRIMARY_COLOR}
          placeholder="Search..."
          onChangeText={(val) => searchName(val)}
          // value={search}
        />
      </Div>
    </Div>
  );
};
```

Comment: still have error, the data got search from flatlist, but now. The data don't show at first come to the screen but when u search some the data appear